# How to build custom event with delay

Tags: javascript

I wrote the below custom event, which is working fine.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.addEventListener('tick', event =>
    this.timerElem.setAttribute('datetime', event.detail.time)
  );
}

connectedCallback() {
  this.timer = setInterval(() =>
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tick', {
      detail: {
        time: new Date()
      }
    })), 1000);
}
```

I tried to split the `even` into another file, but failed to get it run, I wrote:

```
var tick_event = setInterval(() => {
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tick', {
  // window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tick', {
    detail: {
      time: new Date()
    }
  }));
  console.log('test'); // this is print out
}, 1000);
```

Is there a way to do something like this!!

**UPDATE**

In response to the note, if the question is not clear, the below code, worked fine with me:

```
// file: timer.js, one file only
customElements.define("live-timer", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.innerHTML = `
        <time-formatted hour="numeric" minute="numeric" second="numeric">
        </time-formatted>
        `;

      this.timerElem = this.firstElementChild;

      this.addEventListener('tick', event =>
        this.timerElem.setAttribute('datetime', event.detail.time)
      );
  }

  connectedCallback() {
      this.timer = setInterval(() =>
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tick', {
            detail: {
              time: new Date()
            }
          }))
      , 1000);
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    clearInterval(this.timer); // important to let the element be garbage-collected
  }
});
```

The below code did not work fully, and did not give any error:

```
// file: timer.js, first file
customElements.define("live-timer", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.innerHTML = `
        <time-formatted hour="numeric" minute="numeric" second="numeric">
        </time-formatted>
        `;

      this.timerElem = this.firstElementChild;

      this.addEventListener('tick', event =>
        this.timerElem.setAttribute('datetime', event.detail.time)
      );
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    clearInterval(this.timer); // important to let the element be garbage-collected
  }
});

// file: timer trigger, the second file:
var tick_event = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('tick');   // <===================== this works fine
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tick', {   // <== this is not returning anything
      detail: {
        time: new Date()
      }
    }));
    console.log('test'); }
, 1000);
```

With the second option, I got no error, and no result.

Comment: There's no reason in theory why it shouldn't work. But "failed to get it run" is not information we can use to help you. You've got enough reputation here already that I shouldn't really need to say this, but you need to provide some useful detail about the problem as well (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). e.g. some context for how you've loaded this file into your page, any error messages or other information you've collected from the browser's Developer Tools (including console, debugger and network tool), etc.

Comment: If you're including a separate JS file in a web page, some problems to watch out for include: getting the URL of the file wrong, setting permissions of the file incorrectly on the webserver, loading scripts which depend on each other in the wrong order, finding HTTP errors when loading the file (visible in the Network tool), finding syntax / runtime errors (visible in the Console).

Comment: @ADyson I updated the question, part of the file is working, so nothing wrong in files connection.

Comment: Ok I think I see now. It was visible in your original post, but the fact you started talking about separate files distracted me from a change in the code which would have broken it whether you used different files or not. It's not that your events aren't being fired, it's that you're not detecting them. You're now using `window` as the event target (i.e. I mean this: `window.dispatchEvent`). So when you want to listen for that event, you have to listen on `window` instead. Therefore `this.addEventListener('tick', event =>` should be changed to `window.addEventListener('tick', event =>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came with is to do it with `window` as it looks both even `trigger` and `listener` should ne the same `element` (hope someone to correct me if wrong), so I added the event to the `window`, listen it from there, and push the required to my element, i.e. if I need to do the same `tick_listner` for multiple elements, I've to to push to all of them at once.

```
// tick_event.js
var tick_event = setInterval(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tick', {
      detail: {
        time: new Date()
      }
    }));
 }
, 1000);

window.addEventListener('tick', event =>
  $("#timer").timerElem.setAttribute('datetime', event.detail.time)
);
```